# How to re-register geofence in Oreo

Tags: android, geolocation, android-8.0-oreo, android-broadcast, android-geofence

My application uses Geofence to notify user that device entered to specific location or Geofence works fine up to marshmallow but in Oreo it does not as in Oreo provider change broadcast can not be registered in menifest so can not get broadcast event when gps is toggled by users, and we know we have to re-register the geofence on gps toggle as per documentation. So how to register the geofence on gps toggle.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use JobScheduler and keep on registering geofence every few hours.